# How to embed resource file into the exe

Tags: c#

I created some resources files for each language. When I build it creates a folder with a file, like `en/myapp.resources.dll`. Is there a way to embed this in the .exe so that I don't need this extra file?

Comment: It's dll with project library? Then: http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/people/mbarnett/ilmerge.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at this:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/0c6xyb66%28v=vs.100%29.aspx

It describes the file properties you can set on any file in VisualStudio.

Include your resource files in your solution and set the Build Action property to "Embedded Resource".
You will probably next wonder how to access them from your code. Here's a description:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/alexdan/archive/2007/12/19/loading-embedded-resources-in-c-using-getmanifestresourcestream.aspx

Comment: The second link is dead, this one isn't https://stackoverflow.com/a/3314213/366064